# Create index on create table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, create-table

Can I create an index on a `CREATE TABLE` statement?
I.e. can I define indexes for a table when I create the table? I mean create the index on the create stamement sql command

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it can be defined in the `CREATE TABLE`, the convention is to put these definitions at the end of the list.

```
CREATE TABLE `example`
(
    `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `index_col` VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `index_name` (`index_col`)
)
```

Comment: The only relevant answer. +1

Comment: As a caveat, in PostgreSQL it is not possible to add an index in the CREATE TABLE command. This requires a separate CREATE INDEX command.